# RxSwift practice to show/hide ActivityIndicator

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Let's say we have this pseudocode representing a network request call and show/hide an activity indicator, using RxSwift:

```
func performRequest() {
   isLoading.accept(true)
   self.network.executeRequest()
       .subscribe(onNext: {
           self.isLoading.accept(false)
       }, onError: {
           self.isLoading.accept(false)
       })
}
```

The function `executeRequest` returns either an `Observable` or `Single`.

I am not feeling comfortable with having to write twice the same code, for onNext/onSuccess and onError, basically doing the same.

I am looking for suggestions to minimize/improve turning off the activity indicator, like for example handling all events of the request in a single statement and avoid using the `subscribe` function. Or maybe there are other suggestions?

Comment: I am a bit confused about: The function `executeRequest` returns either an `Observable` or `Single`. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: @Erumaru that's just pseudocode, which means that the function `executeRequests` is just a fictive one, but which actually represents  network related functions, which either return an Observable or a Single.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer to cover both cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [ActivityIndicator](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/78f2dd64f12c09b5bc31ef719e55b1a4c4da0d3d/RxExample/RxExample/Services/ActivityIndicator.swift) from RxSwift Example app, which makes it really convenient, especially if your loading multiple things in parallel as it maintains a count of running subscriptions and emit `false` only when this count is equal to 0:

```swift
let isLoading = ActivityIndicator()

func performRequests() {
   self.network
       .executeFirstRequest()
       .trackActivity(isLoading)
       .subscribe { 
           // ...
       }

   self.network
       .executeSecondRequest()
       .trackActivity(isLoading)
       .subscribe { 
           // ...
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jegnux. Looks like that's what I need.

Comment: I was going to answer this question, but the above is exactly what I would have suggested, so I upvoted it. Good answer @jegnux!

Comment: @jednux I am a bit confused now. It looks like `ActivityIndicator` doesn't come with RxSwift library. It is only available in the RxExample folder. Does it mean I need to just copy/paste the code to use it? Or am I missing an `import` or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use another method to subscribe, which passes `Event` in case of `Observer` or `SingleEvent` in case of `Single`:

```
subscribe(on: (Event<T>) -> Void)
subscribe(observer: (SingleEvent<T>) -> Void)
```

---

### Observer Example:

```
func performRequest() {
    isLoading.accept(true)
    self.network.executeRequest().subscribe {
        switch $0 {
        case let .error(error):
            print(error)
        case let .next:
            print("good")
        case .completed:
            print("also good")
        }
        isLoading.accept(false)
    }
}
```

---

### Single Example:

```
func performRequest() {
    isLoading.accept(true)
    self.network.executeRequest().subscribe {
        switch $0 {
        case let .error(error):
            print(error)
        case let .next:
            print("good")
        }
        isLoading.accept(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  My question in this case I guess was not that complete :/.  I know about this `subscribe` function, which would solve my issue. The thing is that I want to avoid using subscribe. I would rather use the `do` function, but that doesn't have something similar.

Comment: @OlegDanu hm, okay. Then, I didn't get the question.

Comment: @OlegDanu you can have a look at PromiseKit, as an option. https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit

Comment: Not that much reasons to add another dependency.

Comment: @OlegDanu okay, I'll leave my answer here, may help someone else. Hope you find your answers!